# how to create dynamic columns using loop in SELECT query through sql client command prompt

Tags: mysql, select, dynamic-columns

How to create and display columns dynamically using loop in SELECT QUERY using mysql client command prompt through SELECT query?

```
SELECT 

for(;@i<=31;@i:=@i+1)
 SELECT fun_proc2(@i,'January',2014) AS CONCAT('d',@i)
   FROM att_t_register r,(SELECT @i:=1) t WHERE CHR_MONTH ='January' 
    AND INT_YEAR =2014;
```

I want columns like

```
 1. d1 d2   d3   d4 ........d31
    =========================

    8   8    8   S  ........-
```

Please help me

Comment: I don't know you if you can put a for loop in select statement but you can use dynamic query and prepared statement in sp. look for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Is it possible to display columns dynamically using for loop in select query